# c# Automapper ITypeConverter destination always null

Tags: c#, automapper

i have a problem with Automapper ITypeConverter. I have two objects ClientDto and Client like this:

```
public class ClientDto
{
     // Other propertis...
     public List<string> Scopes { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
     // Other propertis...
     public List<ClientScope> Scopes {get; set;}
}
```

and object ClientScope like this:

```
public class ClientScope
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Scope { get;set; }
     .....
}
```

I want map Scopes from ClietDto to Client only if the string value is different from the scope in ClientScope object.
I have written my custom TypeConvertr like this:

```
public class StringToScopesConvert : ITypeConverter<string, ClientScope>
{
    public ClientScope Convert(string source, ClientScope destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source.Equals(destination.Scope))
            return destination;

        return new ClientScope
        {
            Scope = source
        };
    }
}
```

In my profile i register them:

```
CreateMap<ClientDto, Client>()
CreateMap<string, ClientScope>().ConvertUsing<StringToScopesConvert>();
```

but when i map them

```
_mapper.Map(clientDto, client);
```

it throws always an exception because destination object in Convert method is null.
How can i solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Upgrade AutoMapper.

Comment: The latest version of automapper is installed. Vers 10.0.0

Comment: Then the destination object you pass to `Map` must be null.

Comment: I edited my question for more clarification, please can you re-examine it. Thanks

Comment: Check AutoMapper.Collection or write the code yourself in a custom resolver for the `Scopes` property.

Comment: Finally, I used AutoMapper.Collection and it works perfectly. Thanks @Lucian Bargaoanu